# Как с помощью jQuery скопировать ссылку и применить ее к текстовому блоку

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
div span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="txt-block">Произвольный текст</span>
  <span class="wrapper-link"><a class="link" href="https://yandex.ru/">Подробнее</a></span>
</div>
```

Подскажите как можно с помощью  jQuery при загрузке страницы скопировать ссылку и применить ее к блоку с текстом и после этого саму ссылку удалить.

Другими словами чтобы span с текстом "Произвольный текст" стал ссылкой, адрес ссылки берется из ссылки  с классом `link` , после этого span с исходной ссылкой / классом  `wrapper-link` удаляется.

Буду признателен за ответ в виде скрипта, если такое конечно вообще возможно сделать с помощью jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.div-link').each(function() {
    const src = $('.wrapper-link', this);
    const link = $('a', src);
    const dst = $('.txt-block', this);
    link.text($(dst).text());
    $(dst).text('').append(link);
    src.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
div span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-link">
  <span class="txt-block">Yandex</span>
  <span class="wrapper-link"><a class="link" href="https://yandex.ru/">Подробнее</a></span>
</div>
<div class="div-link">
  <span class="txt-block">Google</span>
  <span class="wrapper-link"><a class="link" href="https://google.com/">Подробнее</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за рабочее решение! Задача поставленная в вопросе решена почти полностью, (атрибуты ссылки также копируются в txt блок, что вдвойне хорошо). Но есть один нюанс, можно ли как-то сделать чтобы исходный текст тестового блока не заменялся текстом ссылки, а именно слова "Произвольный текст" стали ссылкой?

Comment: @Slava так хотели?

Comment: Сейчас все работает на 100% как и требовалось, текстовый блок становится ссылкой с адресом из источника, и после этого ссылка-источник удаляется со страницы!! Огромное спасибо за изящное решение!!!

Comment: Еще вопрос возник: ссылка копируется во все текстовые блоки на странице с классом txt-block, возможно ли как то сделать чтобы данный скрипт работал в рамках одного DIV где находится эта пара источник+текстовые блок? В другом аналогичном блоке другая ссылка применяется к другому текстовому блоку и т.д.

Comment: @Slava ну вот так

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Еще один вопрос возник) Ваш скрипт работает безупречно, при загрузке странице происходит добавление ссылок текстовым блокам, при этом скрипт обрабатывает каждый блок отдельно, просто супер. Но есть один момент: скрипт срабатывает только один раз при первоначальной загрузке страницы, потом при AJAX обновлении страницы (когда она обновляется без перезагрузки), все блоки снова начинают быть в исходном виде. Существует ли способ заставить ваш скрипт срабатывать неограниченное количество раз при AJAX обновлении страницы?

Comment: @Slava Существует. Нужно вынести его в отдельную функцию и вызывать эту функцию как при загрузке страницы так и после обработки ajax ответа

Comment: А как это сделать в виде скрипта? Я слабо разбираюсь в jquery. В сети нашел информацию что нужно ваш скрипт расположить внутри функции `$('body').on('......', '.......', function() {})` но как это применить к вашему скрипту я не знаю и соответственно не могу проверить рабочий ли это вариант. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: @Slava я думаю, что этот вопрос целесообразно оформить отдельным постом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286780