# Как сделать чтобы jquery скрипт срабатывал при ajax обновлении страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующий скрипт:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.div-link').each(function() {
    const src = $('.wrapper-link', this);
    const link = $('a', src);
    const dst = $('.txt-block', this);
    link.text($(dst).text());
    $(dst).text('').append(link);
    src.remove();
  });
});
```

При первоначальной загрузке страницы скрипт срабатывает на 100%, а далее при AJAX обновлении страницы повторно не срабатывает. Какую функцию нужно добавить к данному скрипту, чтобы он срабатывал как при первоначальной загрузке страницы, так и неограниченное количество раз при AJAX обновлении страницы?

Буду признателен за ответ в виде скрипта!

Comment: " далее при AJAX обновлении страницы " -- что вы вкладываете в понятие " AJAX обновлении страницы "?  Полный html и код с ajax покажите пжлст

Comment: Полный код к сожалению показать не смогу. Проект на локальном сервере, а как воспроизвести всю конструкции в связке с AJAX обновлением страницы в рамках stackoverflow у меня не хватит знаний. AJAX обновление не как не связано с данным скриптом, оно происходит при нажатии на определенные ссылки которые также не связаны с скриптом, просто после AJAX обновления страницы обнуляются все результаты которые делает данный скрипт при первой загрузке страницы, и сам скрипт повторно не запускается, если физически обновить страницу (F5) то опять все срабатывает, но до первого AJAX события

Answer (score 1):

Как предположение. Надо вынести этот код в отдельную функцию и вызывать когда понадобится.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    doWork();  
});

$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    doWork();
});

function doWork() {
    $('.div-link').each(function() {
        const src = $('.wrapper-link', this);
        const link = $('a', src);
        const dst = $('.txt-block', this);
        link.text($(dst).text());
        $(dst).text('').append(link);
        src.remove();
  });
}
```